# Is it possible to lock on to enemies in Epic Mickey?

Tags: epic-mickey

The game manual does not mention locking on, nor does the in game video that describes combat.  However, numerous reviews mention the fact that they found the combat difficult / annoying until they learned of the lock on feature.  On the other hand, just as many reviews complain about the lack of a lock on feature.

Does such a feature exist?  If so, how do you lock on to enemies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a lock on feature, since I finally managed to figure out how to activate it.

If you hold down <kbd>C</kbd> while an enemy is in view, then the screen will "compress" (the top and bottom of the screen disappear) and the camera moves to keep Mickey and the enemy in view.  Pressing <kbd>C</kbd> again resets the screen and the camera.

Comment: So many reviewers couldn't figure that out?  It's not like there's that many buttons.. and that's the same button you use in Twilight Princess!